# I want to change in a TEX file : string a\a{nn}o into a(nn)o

Tags: find-and-replace

I have a `.tex` file in which I want to replace the string `a\a{nn}o` with `a(nn)o`

I have tried the following PowerShell (v5) code:

```
(Get-Content h:\combined.tex) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "a\a{nn}o", "a(nn)o" } `
    | Set-Content h:\combined2.tex
```

It runs, but nothing changes in the text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If [Jeff's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1291059/i-want-to-change-in-a-tex-file-string-a-anno-into-anno/1291060#comment1911733_1291060) points to the source of the problem, then using `"a\\a\{nn\}o"` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following:

```
$(Get-Content .\temp) -replace "123","ABC" | Set-Content temp2
```

The *for* loop is unnecessary, and I believe it (or the pipe) may be causing the problem

Comment: `-replace` uses regular expressions, which may cause problems with the querent's search and replace strings.